# UISearchBar overlaps with UITableView content when active

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a view controller with a table view and a UISearchController.  When running the app, I found that the search bar overlaps the content when it is active.  What do I need to adjust to make the content not be overlapped when search bar is active?

Normal view:

[image]

Search bar is active:

[image]

View controller settings:

[image]

Comment: Did you do `edgesForExtendedLayout = .None` and `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`?

Comment: @ozgur No I didn't.  I have included a screenshot of the settings.

Comment: Your search bar is below the nav bar in one picture and in it in another, explain how it's presented and what it's a subview of

Comment: why can't you use autolayout ?

Comment: @rakeshNS I am using autolayout

Comment: I am still facing the same issue .....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is because of you have  `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true`

please uncheck that [image]

will help :)

Comment: Thanks - this along with a change to layout constraint fixes it.

Comment: Should Adjust Scroll View Insets usually be turned off for table view?

Comment: ya even when i  am  doing with autolayout , i preferred to  turned it off

Comment: Thanks - will award bounty tomorrow.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue .....  my section header overlaps with tableHeaderView

Comment: Try to uncheck under top bars @mihirmehta

Answer (score 1):

You can use the '**UISearchController**' in this manner:

```
_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsTableController];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

// we want to be the delegate for our filtered table so didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called for both tables
self.resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO; // default is YES
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; // so we can monitor text changes + others

// Search is now just presenting a view controller. As such, normal view controller
// presentation semantics apply. Namely that presentation will walk up the view controller
// hierarchy until it finds the root view controller or one that defines a presentation context.
//
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;  // know where you want UISearchController to be displayed
```

You can use this working [Apple Reference Sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html) for more detail.

Comment: you should place 'SearchBar' it in the table's headerview.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to put your SearchBar in the header of TableView.**

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your viewDid().

source: [apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/displaying_searchable_content_by_using_a_search_controller)

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    // For iOS 11 and later, place the search bar in the navigation bar.
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController

    // Make the search bar always visible.
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
} else {
    // For iOS 10 and earlier, place the search controller's search bar in the table view's header.
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to unhiding search bar while scrolling on iOS 11.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
  navigationItem.searchController = searchController
  navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
} else {
  // Fallback on earlier versions
  tableView?.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```